# error :Could not find an implementation of query for source type datatable and join not found while trying to join two datatables

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Not able join two tables using linq - I'm getting this error

> Could not find an implementation of query for source type datatable and join not found while trying to join two datatables

Any possible solutions please

```
DataSet dsSales = OfflineBilling.CreateDatasetFromXML("Salesmaster.xml");

DataTable dtmaster = dsSales.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ReceiptId") == ReceiptId.ToString()).CopyToDataTable();
DataTable dtitems = dsSales.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ReceiptId") == ReceiptId.ToString()).CopyToDataTable();

var query = from d in dtmaster
            join c in dtitems on d.ReceiptId equals c.ReceiptId
            .Select(m => new
                        {
                            ReceiptId = d.ReceiptId
                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
        DataSet dsSales = OfflineBilling.CreateDatasetFromXML("Salesmaster.xml");
        DataTable dtmaster = dsSales.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ReceiptId") == ReceiptId.ToString()).CopyToDataTable();
        DataTable dtitems = dsSales.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("ReceiptId") == ReceiptId.ToString()).CopyToDataTable();


        var query = from d in dtmaster.AsEnumerable()
                    join c in dtitems.AsEnumerable() on d.Field<string>("ReceiptId") equals c.Field<string>("ReceiptId")
                    .Select(new
                    {
                        ReceiptId = d.Field<string>("ReceiptId")
                    });
```

Comment: thank you for seeing into but It is showing as consider swapping the exprssions and body should end with select errors .

Answer (score 0):

DataSet dsSales = OfflineBilling.CreateDatasetFromXML("Salesmaster.xml");
        DataTable dtmaster = dsSales.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field("ReceiptId") == ReceiptId.ToString()).CopyToDataTable();
        DataTable dtitems = dsSales.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field("ReceiptId") == ReceiptId.ToString()).CopyToDataTable();

```
    var query = from d in dtmaster.AsEnumerable()
                join c in dtitems.AsEnumerable() on d.Field<string>("ReceiptId") equals c.Field<string>("ReceiptId")
                .Select(new
                {
                    ReceiptId = d.Field<string>("ReceiptId")
                });
```

Actually its working after removing m =>  in your answer, thank you.